# Sorting objects by a particular property

Tags: java, comparator

I am suppose to compare two courses and sort them alphabetically by course name, however I noticed that I cant use either "<" or ">". Is there another way to compare if the course should be greater or less than another.

```
import java.util.Comparator;

/**
 * A class that overrides the natural order comparison of courses to order
 * them alphabetically by course name.
 *
 */
public class CourseComparator implements Comparator<Course> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Course o1, Course o2) {
        if(o1.getName() == o2.getName()){
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        if(o1.getName() < o2.getName())
            return 1;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question has to do with your title. No, there's no `<` operator for strings, but you can call `o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName())` potentially. Note that you should *not* be comparing strings with `==`. I'm assuming `getName()` returns `String` of course - you haven't actually said...

Comment: use `compareTo()` for everything.

Comment: What do you want it to mean for 1 course to be greater than another? What is a `Course`? Did the string comparator not work if this is a String wrapper?

Comment: Course is just another class. Its fields are course id, course name, and course level. What i want to do is order the courses by their names alphabetically.

Comment: Can you use TreeSet ?

Comment: If `getName()` returns a `String` (or other comparable object), your method body needs just one line, `return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());`. Or even simpler, instead of declaring a new class you get a comparator from `Comparator.comparing(Course::getName)` (this requires at least Java 8).

Comment: Please, has your title, “Adding and Removing via HashSet”, anything to do with the question? Asking because if it has, I probably misunderstood what the question was.

Comment: One mor hint: You shouldn't compare Strings with the == operator! Always use equals() for those comparisons.

Comment: If you have `compareTo` in your `Course`, why do you need this `Comparator`? The call to `compareTo` in your `Comparator` is not good; it requires that the comparator use dark knowledge of a method that theoretically could change, and at least we cannot tell what the difference is between the comparisons. The `Comparator` should only work with the getters for the `Course` attributes and not with other methods from there.

Answer (score 1):

#### Operators

- `==` 
  If both operands are Primitive Data Types it will do a value comparison. String is a Class not a Primitive Data Type.
- `<` `>` 
  Are Operators and are only reasonable with Primitive Data Types like int, double ...

#### Object Comparison

- `==` 
  Will compare to objects if they are the same object.
- `.equals(Object o)`
  Will compare two objects if there Values are the same. Therefore you can overload this method you have to check what the author of the Class means by 'equal'. For the String Class `.equals` means same String.
- `.compareTo(String s)`
  Is the String comparison in the meaning of before(-), after(+) and equals(0).

#### Your Example

Just using `.compareTo` on the both **`.getName()`**

```
public class CourseComparator implements Comparator<Course> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Course o1, Course o2) {
        return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
    }
}
```

#### Interface Comparable

By the Way you could implement the `Interface Comparable` than the sorting Options of `Arrays.sort(Object[] a)` or `Collections.sort(List<T> list))` don't need a comparator.

```
public class Course implements Comparable<Course> {
    ...
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Course otherCourse) {
        return getName().compareTo(otherCourse.getName());
    }
}
```